# JS: How to print elements in a for loop with distinct #ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I want to print out with jQuery, several html elements, and each element should have a distinct #id.

My code does output the elements, but I don´t know how to make them different.

```
<input type='button' onclick="generarTabla(5)" name='submit' value='How Many?'>
<div id="output"></div>

function generarTabla(cant) {
var numero = 1;
var celda = "Mes <input type='text' name='nro"+numero+"'><br>";
for ($i=0; $i<cant; $i++) { 
    $('#output').append(celda);
    }     
}
```

**Each line should be like this:**

```
Mes <input type='text' name='nro1'><br>
Mes <input type='text' name='nro2'><br>
Mes <input type='text' name='nro3'><br>
```

etc.

**And right now it outputs like this:**

```
Mes <input type='text' name='nro1'><br>
Mes <input type='text' name='nro1'><br>
Mes <input type='text' name='nro1'><br>
```

[Here´s a copy of the code at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rosamunda/tRKYt/3/)

Comment: put the `celda` assignment inside your loop and use `i` instead of `numero` in your `name` attribute

Comment: If you want to create three different elements, then you have to create them inside the loop, not create one outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the constructor inside the loop and use the loop variable

```
function generarTabla(cant) {
    for ($i=0; $i<cant; $i++) { 
        var celda = "Mes <input type='text' name='nro"+($i+1)+"'><br>";
        $('#output').append(celda);
    }     
}
```